# Python: Printing elements in the defaultdict based on the order in the OrderedDict

Tags: python, numpy, ordereddictionary, defaultdict

```
import string
from collections import namedtuple
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import OrderedDict

matrix_col = {'11234':0, '21234':2, '31223':0, '46541':0, '83432':1, '56443':2, '63324':0, '94334':0, '72443':1}
matrix_col = OrderedDict(sorted(matrix_col.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))

trans = defaultdict(dict)
trans['11234']['46541'] = 2
trans['11234']['21234'] = 1
trans['11234']['31223'] = 2
trans['11234']['83432'] = 1
trans['21234']['31223'] = 2
trans['21234']['46541'] = 1
trans['21234']['72443'] = 1
trans['21234']['83432'] = 1
trans['56443']['72443'] = 1
trans['56443']['83432'] = 1

for u1, v1 in matrix_col.items():
    for u2, v2 in matrix_col.items():
        for w1 in trans.keys():
            for w2, c in trans[u1].items():
                if u1 == str(w1) and u2 == str(w2):
                    print u1, u2, c
```

As above, I am trying to print the elements of **trans** (defaultdict) based on the sorted order of the elements in the **matrix_col** (OrderedDict) and unable to do that. Below is the expected output, which I can't generate:

```
11234 11234 0
11234 21234 1
11234 31223 2
11234 46541 2
11234 56443 0
11234 63324 0
11234 72443 0
11234 83432 1
11234 94334 0
21234 11234 0
21234 21234 0
21234 31223 2
21234 46541 1
21234 56443 0
21234 63324 0
21234 72443 1
21234 83432 1
21234 94334 0
31223 11234 0
31223 21234 0
31223 31223 0
31223 46541 0
31223 56443 0
31223 63324 0
31223 72443 0
31223 83432 0
31223 94334 0
...
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since you're clearly writing Python 2 code, I need to point out: `if u1 in trans.keys():` is an awful line of code. `trans.keys()` on Python 2 creates a fresh `list` of the keys, so you're making a largish object every time you test, then scanning it linearly for a hit, instead of doing a `O(1)` membership test directly with `if u1 in trans:`. Similarly, the majority of uses of `.items()` should probably be `.iteritems()` or `.viewitems()` to iterate directly instead of making `list`s that copy them (plain `.keys()`/`.items()` is only useful if you'll be mutating the `dict` during iteration).

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard way (that I know of) to sort a dictionary based on an arbitrary sort on an OrderedDict, but you can always sort by the same thing. In this case, simply a default sort should be sufficient.

```
for k, sub_dct in sorted(trans.items()):
    for sub_k, v in sorted(sub_dct.items()):
        print k, sub_k, v
```

the alternative, I suppose, would be traversing the OrderedDict twice and doing a lookup against the defaultdict.

```
for k in matrix_col:
    for sub_k in matrix_col:
        v = trans.get(k, {}).get(sub_k, 0)
        print k, sub_k, trans[k][sub_k]
```

Comment: Thank you. Though, your option #1 doesn't generate the output I am looking for. It only generates the output with the existing elements in the **trans**. Your option #2 gives the following error: _TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'_

Comment: @JamesDerrick bah that's because I made a simple error. The adjusted bottom code should work. I don't understand your comment about option #1, though -- if you're trying to do something other than generate output from the existing elements in `trans` it's unclear in your question.

Comment: I apologize if I didn't make it clear: There is an OrderedDict, **matrix_col**. There is also a defaultdict, **trans**. I need to iterate all elements of **trans** by the order of **matrix_col** and print. If the **matrix_col** element exists in the **trans**, print its value c  along. If not, print the element in the **matrix_col** with value 0. Please take a look at the expected output. It is really self explanatory. With your code, you are just printing what is in **trans**. Can you also print other elements that are in **matrix_col** yet not in **trans** with their value being 0? Thank you

Comment: @JamesDerrick ah ha, then yes!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it. Here it is:

```
for u1, v1 in matrix_col.items():
    for u2, v2 in matrix_col.items():
        bastim = True
        for w1 in trans.keys():
            for w2, c in trans[u1].items():
                if u1 == str(w1) and u2 == str(w2):
                    print u1, u2, c  
                    bastim = False
        if bastim:
            print u1, u2, 0
```

Thank you all.

Comment: but this prints more than the elements of `trans`.  It includes pairs that you never put in `trans`.

Comment: @hpaulj apparently this was intended behavior. I didn't get that either.

Answer (score 0):

This iteration works:

```
for u1 in matrix_col:
    d = trans[u1]
    # d may be empty dict
    for u2 in matrix_col:
        print u1, u2, d.get(u2, 0)
```

Look at `trans` before this iteration:

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {
   '21234': {'31223': 2, '46541': 1, '72443': 1, '83432': 1}, 
   '11234': {'21234': 1, '31223': 2, '46541': 2, '83432': 1}, 
   '56443': {'83432': 1, '72443': 1}
  })
```

There are entries for '21234', '11234'  and '56443';  When the iteration uses another `u1`, `d` will be an empty dict, `{}`. `d.get` takes care of returning a meaningful value (`0`) in case the `u2` isn't present.

The `defaultdict` will add entries for every key you reference, but you have to reference it first.  Iterating on `trans.keys()` does not generate new keys.  Your initial iteration did what you describe - `print the elements of trans (defaultdict)`.

Your boolean `bastim` takes care of the same issue - filling in 0s that aren't in `trans`.

If `trans` is a `defaultdict` of `defautdicts` than the iteration can be a tad simpler:

```
def foo():
    # the inner dict defaults to 0
    return defaultdict(int)    
trans = defaultdict(foo)
for u1 in matrix_col:
    d = trans[u1]
    for v1 in matrix_col:
        print u1,v1, d[v1]
```

This would be more interesting if the inner dict collected values in a list

```
def foo():
    return defaultdict(list)
trans = defaultdict(foo)
```

and the additions used `append` (and repeated)

```
trans['11234']['46541'].append(2)
trans['11234']['21234'].append(1)
trans['11234']['31223'].append(2)
trans['11234']['83432'].append(1)

trans['11234']['46541'].append(5)
trans['11234']['21234'].append(3)
trans['11234']['31223'].append(4)
```

producing

```
11234 11234 []
11234 21234 [1, 3]
11234 31223 [2, 4]
11234 46541 [2, 5]
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I expanded on your own answer. This code seems equivalent and runs around 3 times as fast, although not sure if you are constrained by CPU, and it may not run on python < 2.7 (operator.methodcaller). (obviously the better performance option is just to use C or try and take advantage of numpy matrix operations)

```
            items=matrix_col.items()
            import operator
            for (u1, v1), trans_u1_items in zip(items,map(operator.methodcaller('items'), map(trans.__getitem__,matrix_col))):
                for u2, v2 in items:
                    bastim = True
                    for w1 in trans:
                        for w2, c in trans_u1_items:
                            if u1 == w1 and u2 == w2:
                                print u1, u2, c
                                bastim = False
                    if bastim:
                        pass
                        print u1, u2, 0
```